# NSNumber is converted to NSDate even after making new instance of NSNumber

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsnumber

I have a property on my class that is of type NSNumber.

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *createdDate;
```

I want it to stay NSNumber for the life of the class.  However, I want to make a date out of it when another class requests it.

For that I made a method called getCreatedDate

Here is the method that I created

```
 - (NSDate *)getCreatedDate
 {
   NSNumber *copyCreatedDate = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[self.createdDate doubleValue]];
   NSDate *dateFromNumber = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[copyCreatedDate doubleValue]];
   return dateFromNumber;
 }
```

The problem is after that method is run, I check to see what type the property self.createdDate is and it tells me its of type NSDate.

Does anyone know if what I want to do it possible?

Comment: How are you "checking to see"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your method name. **getCreatedDate** will represent the getter method of the  **createdDate** object. So after implementing this method, u returned NSDate datatype. Thats why the type changes to  **NSDate** . So you have to change the name to another

Comment: The auto-synthesized getter is `createdDate` not `getCreatedDate`

Comment: your right!  Prime example of why one shouldn't be writing code all day and late into the night. thanks!